# Can I ask an iostream if it is writeable?

Tags: c++, iostream

In my code I am passed a reference to an iostream, that in this case is ultimately a file.
Is there any way to find out if, when it was opened, it was set to [in|out] not just [in]?

Comment: Is it actually an `iostream &`?  If so, it inherits from both `istream` and `ostream`, and, hence, is writable.  If you're taking a reference to the base class, `ios`, then you're looking at either using RTTI or templated functions.

Comment: std::fstream f("/work/file.txt", std::ios_base::in); - f inherits ostream but is not writable.

Comment: But why would you do that, except to annoy people who want to find out if they can write to the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at all the members of IOS, iostream, ostream, i did not see any way to retrieve the `openmode` flag used. I guess you'll have to try to write something to your reference and catch any error it throws. Or depending on how it is set, check the result of bad().

Answer (score 1):

The `openmode` is passed down to `std::streambuf`, but there are no methods to retrieve it. The only way to know if the file is open for write operations is trying to write and checking for `f.fail()`, or optionally `f.bad()` (equivalent to `f.rdstate() & std::fstream::badbit`).

Answer (score -2):

...kind of

```
if ( dynamic_cast<ostream*>( MyStreamPtr ) == 0 )
{
    // Not for output...
}
```